# onClick event not working using innerHTML with dayRender in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I need to add a button on a day in dayGridMonth view that has an onClick event.

`if (date.getTime()===today.getTime()){ el.innerHTML ='<button id="buttonID" onclick="handleClick();">TITLE</button>'; } ,`

it will add HTML but onClick event doesn't work

Comment: Is there any error throwing in browser console (Chrome Developer Tools) while clicking newly added button ?

Comment: No. there isn't any error.button added to dom. but there is not any event binded to the element.
$._data( $("#buttonID")[0], "events" )==> return undefined

Comment: Can you please share your fullcalendar code..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/elhka90/x2wyp8ed/5/

Comment: The fiddle is not working for me.. There is js error coming on Calendar object not found.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follow:

```
if (date.getTime()===today.getTime()){ 
  el.innerHTML ='<button id="titleButton">TITLE</button>'; 
}
```

Please check that there are two } in your code before ,

Than add following code on top of fullcalendar code:

```
document.getElementById("titleButton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    handleClick();
});
```

Comment: button added to dom. but there is not any event binded to the element.
$._data( $("#buttonID")[0], "events" )==> return undefined

Comment: #buttonID is not correct.. you may try with #titleButton

Comment: I did it befor. buttonID is just a sample.

Comment: Please check this for example.. http://jsfiddle.net/YXMPn/331/